# AttributeError in Spyder

Tags: python, console, attributeerror

```
    """
    Create and show the Open FileDialog
    """
    plt.close()
    dlg2 = wx.FileDialog(
        self, message="Choose a file",
        defaultFile="",
        wildcard=wildcard, 
        style=wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE) # | wx.CHANGE_DIR  )
```

I want to Run the codes but have an error on these lines.
I don't need anything errors, so please let me know why next error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python_HY/Python_GUI_M_Analysis_2016.0204_trackpy0.3_minor.changes.py", line 4448, in onOpenImageFile
style=wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OPEN'
```

That is the Console of codes. Why AttributeError occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.FileDialog.html) it should be `FD_OPEN`, `FD_MULTIPLE`and `FD_CHANGE_DIR`:

```
dlg2 = wx.FileDialog(
    self, message="Choose a file",
    defaultFile="",
    wildcard=wildcard, 
    style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_MULTIPLE) # | wx.FD_CHANGE_DIR)
```

I am guesing the code you are trying to run might have been writen for an outdated version of `wx`

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer by checking the checkmark next to it so other users know its solved